# nservicebus 4.03 how do you setup publisher/subscriber?

Tags: publisher, subscriber, nservicebus4

how do we setup publisher where the subscription information is stored in the DB?
What all do you need in the configs of publisher and subscribers??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the pub sub sample in the sample directory.

Look [here](http://particular.net/articles/publish-subscribe-configuration) and [here](http://particular.net/articles/how-pub-sub-works).

[This](http://particular.net/articles/publish-subscribe-sample) is a bit out of date but will give you a bit of background.

Hope this helps

Comment: i have got an idea how it works in 3.x but not sure how it can be achieved in 4.x The thing on thier website is for 3.x out dated

Comment: take a look here: http://particular.net/articles/relational-persistence-using-nhibernate---nservicebus-4.x.

dose this help?

Comment: i put up a sample here: https://github.com/sfarmar/Samples/tree/master/PubSubDBSubscriptions/MyPublisher
HTH